# How to perform an action after another one in Android Studio (Java)?

Tags: android, button, android-button

This is some of the current code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class game1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game1);
}

Button loseStarter1;

loseStarter1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Starter1);
loseStarter1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        loseStarter1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    })

}
```

If, for example, I wanted to print a number after the Button 'loseStarter1' is pressed, how would I do so?
This is something I'd like to learn that can be applied for any action after pressing a Button, such as starting an interactive Activity.
Also, would it be in the `onCreate()` method?

Much appreciated, note that I am a beginner.

Comment: You have it above. Just implement the `onClick()` method to do whatever action you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your code won't compile - You closed off the `onCreate` method and `findViewById` must be inside `onCreate` and after `setContentView`.

> would it be in the onCreate method?

Not necessarily in *that* particular method, only after the view has been loaded.

With regards to your question. What exactly do you not understand about how a click event works? You define a button, and then set the action to be "performed after it is clicked".

```
Button loseStarter1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game1);    
    loseStarter1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Starter1);
    loseStarter1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: Perform actions here...
            // action1();
            // action2();
        }
    });
}
```

> for example, I wanted to print a number after the button 'loseStarter1' is pressed, how would I do so?

Assuming `game1` is the class name

```
Toast.makeText(game1.this, String.valueOf(42), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: The Toast line didn't work after adding it to the onClick section beneath setVisibility, and using System.out.println didn't work in another class either.

Comment: **method (not class)

Comment: System.out.println should work, (and you should be using `Log` instead)  But I have corrected the Toast line